# Passing data between multiple uiview in uiscrollview

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uiscrollview

I have a ViewController that contains a uiscrollview and I create 2 uiview as pages inside the uiscrollview with paging and scrolling enabled:

```
_scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(_scrollView.frame.origin.x, _scrollView.frame.origin.y, _scrollView.frame.size.width, _scrollView.frame.size.height);

_scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(_scrollView.frame.size.width, _scrollView.frame.size.height*PAGES_NUMBER);
_scrollView.delegate = self;
[self.view addSubview:_scrollView];

//PAGE 1
    genderViewController = [[GenderViewController alloc]init];
genderViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0.0,
                                             _scrollView.frame.size.height*0,
                                             _scrollView.frame.size.width,
                                             _scrollView.frame.size.height);

[_scrollView addSubview:genderViewController.view];

//PAGE 2
    ageViewController = [[AgeViewController alloc]init];
ageViewController.view.frame =CGRectMake(0.0,
                                         _scrollView.frame.size.height*1,
                                         _scrollView.frame.size.width,
                                         _scrollView.frame.size.height);

[_scrollView addSubview:ageViewController.view];
```

The thing is that I'm wondering how can I pass data between this 2 uiview.
For example, I have a UITextField in the first page "genderViewController" and I want to show this content in and UILabel in the second page "ageViewController" once I scroll to the second page.
I know how to pass data between 2 different view controllers in a navigation view, but I don't know how to do this at this stage.
I would appreciate if you guys could help me with that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty much the same as it is in a navigation view. Aparently your two view controllers are nested in that scroll view which is owned by a third, lets say the master, view controller.

The most clean way of implementing this would be if the view controller with the `UITextField` (`genderViewController`) would call any delegate method that you define of the master view controller. For that the master would set itself as delegate of `genderViewController` (you may need to add a delegate protocol and a setter).

If you want to implement it as in the books, then declare the callback/delegate method in a protocol which the `genderViewController` conforms to.

Upon this method being called your master view controller would call a setter of the `ageViewController`. Within this setter ageViewController will set the value of the `UILable`

Comment: Thanks for the response. But I'm thinking that the it won't work since the 2 view controllers are created all along. I mean, when the app runs then the 2 view controllers are created. After that, I want to type any text in the first page, and I want this text to be updated in the second page label, but since this second page is already created, it won't show the text. Am I right?

Comment: No, you are not right. It would just work. Give it a try. However, the setter of the text of ageViewController must, of course, update the actual text of the UILable. Check the lable for nil, just to be save.

Answer (score 0):

Delegate methods maybe suitable for some specific operations. But I would find it - conceptually - more appropriate to use Key/Value Observing in such cases.

Documentation can be found at: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Articles/KVOCompliance.html

For your case, `ageViewController` can observe changes for a keyPath (say `textField.text`) in `genderViewController`.